# tomcat servlet strange behaviour when deployed using server.xml

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, tomcat9

**EDIT**: Not a tomcat issue. Issue is with browsers caching on having a .jpeg extension from servlet. Disabled caching using the servlet code from response -

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
```

This issue is with tomcat (9 or maybe other versions) as when deployed locally it works fine but when deployed to a server using the server.xml file like below it shows issues

```
<Host name="jobs.nvoids.com"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">        
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
    <Context antiJARLocking="true" docBase="/home/jobs" path="" reloadable="true">                
            
    </Context>  
</Host>
```

I have an servlet which is deployed using web.xml and another i have deployed using annotations.

The servlet with web.xml is [here](https://jobs.nvoids.com/image/captcha-image.jpeg) which on reloading **should** show different captchas but it shows the same after 2 reloads. I checked and saw the request doesn't even reach the servlet.

The servlet with annotations is [here](https://jobs.nvoids.com/testing) and this is working fine and shows different images on each reload.

the web.xml is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CaptchaServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>myPack.CaptchaServlet1</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CaptchaServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/image/captcha-image.jpeg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>    
 </web-app>
```

the servlet code for generating captcha is [here](https://pastebin.com/2x7586Ph)

The tomcat version is 9.0.29

Comment: If the request _doesn't even reach the servlet_, then the chances are high that you have a caching reverse proxy/CDN in the chain, and your captcha implementation does not generate proper do-not-cache headers.

Comment: @OlafKock yes disabled caching from servlet response